# Option buttons modal view ios7

Tags: ios7, uibutton, modalviewcontroller

My objective here is to recreate this option view that Facebook messenger and many other apps use when they are displaying options.[image]

What is the best way to go about doing this? Is there a built in class that will let me do this? Are there good third party apps that will accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after doing some digging what you need is an action sheet. Action sheets are pretty straight forward, to set an action sheet up:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Note"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

To Collect Response

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"The %@ button was tapped.", [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
}
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActionSheet

**Extra:**

Here is an open source modal framework: https://github.com/reednj/TDSemiModal